# Doorkeeper OAuth application table is necessary for authorization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I'm trying to add the Doorkeeper plus devise with google and facebook user authorization on API!

I followed this post https://www.vic-l.com/jwt-with-refresh-token-using-devise-and-doorkeeper-without-authorization

And this:
https://naturaily.com/blog/api-authentication-devise-doorkeeper-setup

To start with, both remove the oauth_applications table.

I've done as the tutorials but I'm getting this response:

```
response_code: "doorkeeper.errors.messages.unsupported_grant_type",…}
response_code: "doorkeeper.errors.messages.unsupported_grant_type"
response_message: "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server."
state: nul
```

So I would like to know if is necessary the oauth_applications table and set the clients to authorize.

Answer (score 0):

Articles you've mentioned uses Resource Owner Password Flow, i.e they are authenticating the user via credentials to give an access to a resources with an access token. See the configuration option:

```
 grant_flows %w[password]
```

In such case yeah, you don't need applications (clients which will interact with the API). But if you want to show an authorization window for your customers you should use [Authorization Code Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow) (from your response I see you're trying to invoke exactly this flow).